# Drupal 8 - How to add a tab in user profile page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I've created a view with path `/user/%/articles` to list all articles authored by the user, and now I want to add it as a tab on the user profile page. I tried to configure the menu in the view's configuration page but I can't tell what should be used as the parent menu.

Does anybody know how to do this correctly?

Comment: May be this help :http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208648/how-do-i-add-custom-tab-in-the-user-profile-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. 
Drupal 8

Path:/user/%user/articles

Menu: User account menu > My account

Answer (score 0):

Url should be /user/%user/articles and menu item entry of the view settings should be set to "menu tab".

All was explaned in this post : https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-creating-views-of-content-in-tabs/